# subscribe and publish in the same class

Tags: ros, c++, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to publish and subscribe to topics from within the same class but cannot figure out how to set up the subscriber callback. Can you explain what to do on line 10 for me? Thanks!
http://pastebin.com/E2qLkcfX

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10797/subscribe-and-publish-in-the-same-class/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Callback_Types) describing different callback types (with example usage of each) might help.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) on 2011-08-02**:
sub = n.subscribe("/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined", 1000,  &Spinner::spin_cb, this); ?

**Comment by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on 2011-08-02**:
I was able to call the class method from within main but I would still like to figure out how to subscribe from within the class: ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("my_topic", 1, &Foo::callback, &foo_object);